# Getting angularjs directive working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Newbie trying to learn more about directives. Would like a directive that puts a red star in front of a label, but only if input for label has the required attribute.

The fiddle I have been working with is here. http://jsfiddle.net/NYNYM/1/

Here is the HTML

```
<body data-ng-app="TestLabel">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" >
            <form name="TestLabelForm" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <jcdc-input-label for="Simple" size="col-md-7" text="Test Label"></jcdc-input-label>
                    <input type="text" name="Simple" required="" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br/>
            Should look like
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <form name="ExampleForm" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Simple2" class="col-md-7"><span style="color:red">*</span>Test Label:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Simple2" required="" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div >

    <!-- Get Javascript -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" >
    </script >
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js" > </script > 
    <script src="js/TestLabel.js" > </script > 
</body >
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('TestLabel', []);

    app.directive('jcdcInputLabel', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<label class="control-label {{size}}" for="{{for}}"><span ng-show="ShowRequired">*</span>{{text}}:</label>',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                size: '@',
                text: '@',
                for: '@'
            },
            link: function ($scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.ShowRequired = false;

                var fieldName = attrs['for'];
                var inputArray = document.FindByName(fieldName);
                scope.ShowRequired = inputArray[0].hasAttribute("required");


            }
        };
    });

})();
```

Any help you have will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your link function - $scope vs scope (I think you meant to put the dollar on one of the vars)

Comment: that's a lot of code for something that could be simply done with css alone

Comment: Thanks charlietfl. I already know css, but am trying to learn angularjs.

Comment: @charlietfl Your comment is thoroughly unhelpful to him. Further, he's just trying to learn so give him a break.

Comment: Does your fiddle run at all?  I think you need to skip the jquery stuff to make your code run on document load and to set the time to run as '`No wrap - in <body>`' under "Frameworks & Extensions": ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/F6a7y/))

Comment: 1) As pixelbits mentioned you are mixing `$scope` and `scope` in your link function.  The link function requires parameters in order and is not injected by name like a controller or the directive itself, so just pick one and use it as the parameter and in the function.

Comment: 2) Using `replace` means the attributes will be copied over to your template element so you should remove the `for` attribute from your template ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2SJfK/)).  Otherwise the attribute ends up being 'Simple Simple' or 'Simple ' (with a space) because of the way angular combines values for attributes.

Comment: 3) The `for: '@'` means you should have a property on your isolated scope called `for` that has the value, or you can use `attrs.for`.  Since for is a keyword in javascript it might be better to use `forValue: "@for",` or just use attrs.

Comment: 4) `document` doesn't have a function `FindByName`, which is ok because of #5

Comment: 5) A label's `for` attribute is for referencing the `id` of an input control, not the name, so add `id="Simple"` to the input and change `document.FindByName` to `document.getElementById` ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2SJfK/))

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - Thank you for this invaluable input!

Comment: Oop2, #5 fiddle was wrong, ([***this fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/VsH3q/1/)) shows the difference between id and name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than fix up your code I'm just going to walk you through creating a directive that accomplishes your goal. Firstly, I think it makes a lot more sense to include the input as part of your directive. It would be a neat little directive that takes the text for the label as an attribute and shows the asterisk if the consumer of your directive includes the `required` attribute. Keep in mind that although @charlietfl wasn't very polite, he was right that this directive is overkill; this is for learning purposes only.

Let's tap out a quick wireframe directive with nothing but the template so we can talk about it.

```
var app = angular.module('TestLabel', []);

app.directive('labeledInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<div>',
            '    <span ng-show="ShowRequired">*</span>',
            '    <label for="{{id}}">{{labelText}}</label>',
            '    <input type="text" id="{{id}}" />',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        }
    };
});
```

You can see already that I've modified the template a little. Normally I'd include the template separately but for this example I've put it into an array and then used the array's `join` method to concatenate all the markup strings together into one string. I find that this technique makes markup strings easier to read when there aren't any good alternatives. Just remember that in the real world you'd want to reference your template which would be stored elsewhere, preferably in a place where your editor can do syntax highlighting and other goodies like you're used to.

Now let's go ahead and define our isolate scope.

```
app.directive('labeledInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<div>',
            '    <span ng-show="ShowRequired">*</span>',
            '    <label for="{{id}}">{{text}}</label>',
            '    <input type="text" id="{{id}}" ng-model="model" />',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            text: '@',
            model: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        }
    };
});
```

Here I've gone ahead and added three properties to our isolate scope. The first is `id` which I simply transfer into the label's `for` attribute and the input's `id` attribute. Next I have `text` which is nothing more than the text that should be displayed on the label. Lastly I have `model`. I supply `model` from our scope to the `ng-model` directive in our template, allowing the input to two-way bind to our scope property `model` which is two-way bound to whatever outer-scope property the user includes in the `model` attribute when using the directive. The equals sign is what specifies that the property should be two-way bound to the outer-scope property supplied.

Now let's fill in our link function and make the magic happen.

```
app.directive('labeledInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<div>',
            '    <span ng-show="required">*</span>',
            '    <label for="{{id}}">{{text}}</label>',
            '    <input type="text" id="{{id}}" ng-model="model" />',
            '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            text: '@',
            model: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.required = attributes.hasOwnProperty('required');
        }
    };
});
```

Much simpler yes? The reason we didn't pass `required` through using the isolate scope syntax is because we merely wanted to see if the attribute was included and we don't care about its value. Now the user simply puts the word `required` on the directive and the asterisk shows up.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <labeled-input id="requiredInput" text="Required Input:"  model="requiredValue" required></labeled-input>
    Required Value: {{ requiredValue }}
</div>
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/hnkA6xFzcg06Xloxgzks?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Got it working for you [at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYNYM/5/)... here's what you missed.

## 1.  When replacing, don't copy attributes over manually.

Like Jason Goemaat said, angular will copy them for you already, so adding them back manually will give you `Simple Simple`.  Just drop the `for="..."` in your template.

## 2.  It's `document.getElementsByName()`

document.FindByName doesn't exist in any browser, as far as I can tell.  Try `getElementsByName()` instead.

## 3.  Watch your variable names

Like Jason said, you've got both `$scope` and `scope`.  The `link` function doesn't use injection, which is why you'll see people use regular `scope` there to help signify that, so I'd follow that example.

## 4.  Don't actually use a directive for this

Like charlietfi said, this isn't a great use case for a directive.  It's good for learning, but you'll find that directives that have to reach outside themselves using jQuery or the document methods are anti-angular and will cause huge headaches.
That's not to say that this is a bad start, though... to make it better, try moving the `<input>` into your template, since this directive requires that `<input>` anyways; it will make it much easier to find the input in your code, and will make your directive serve more of a purpose.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing out my many errors and helping me understand more!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your directive

```
myApp.directive('inputrequired', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            lableText: '@',
            text: '@',
            for: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           if(attrs['required'] &&  attrs['type']=="text")
           {

               var html ='  <label for="Simple2" class="col-md-7"><span style="color:red">*</span>Test Label:</label><input type="text" name="Simple" required/>';
        var e =$compile(html)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(e);    
           }


        }
    };
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/seminda/e8Nj3/13/)